# Proceed to NavLink Conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to click on the NavLink component without immediately proceeding to the path that I set for it. Upon clicking on NavLink, I need to check a condition and, if it is true, set state. If it is false, then only proceed to NavLink path.

**NOTE**: I do **NOT** want to use history.push("/path"). I want to do this using **NavLink** **only**.

```
import React from "react";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

class SomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someVar: false
    };
  }

  someFunction = () => {
     //does some stuff
 }

  onClick = () => {

    someFunction().then( someBool => {
     if(someBool !== undefined) {
         e.preventDefault();             // not working
         setState({someVar: true})
     }
    })

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
            <NavLink to="/anotherPage" onClick={this.onClick}>
              Another Page
            </NavLink>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if user goes directly to `/anotherPage` using url bar ?. So just do that conditioning stuff on that page/component instead of this silly way.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your `onClick` handler consume the click event, and under the correct condition prevent the default action (*and event propagation, if necessary*).

Example:

```
class SomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someVar: false
    };
  }

  onClick = (e) => {
    if (thing is true) {
      e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent link navigation from occurring
      this.setState({ someVar: true });
    } else {
      // allow link navigation to occur
      // proceed to NavLink 
      // this else might not be necessary if it doesn't do anything
      // other than allow the navigation to occur
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <NavLink to="/anotherPage" onClick={this.onClick}>
            Another Page
          </NavLink>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Update

Since it seems the click handler uses asynchronous code you'll need to entirely prevent the default link action and conditionally issue an imperative navigation action via the `history.push`.

```
class SomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someVar: false
    };
  }

  someFunction = async () => { // <-- returns Promise
    //does some stuff
  }

  onClick = target => async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const someBool = await someFunction();
      if (someBool !== undefined) {
        setState({ someVar: true });
      } else {
        this.props.history.push(target);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      // catch and handle any errors/rejected Promises, etc...
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          <NavLink to="/anotherPage" onClick={this.onClick("/anotherPage")}>
            Another Page
          </NavLink>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thank you for your response. I've actually edited my if statement. If I include a e.preventDefault() there, it does not work. Please check if you get a chance!

Comment: Hi Drew, if possible please provide feedback to my above comment! Thank you!

Comment: @penguin The `someFunction` is asynchronous and the link clicking event can't wait for it. What you'll need to do is to entirely prevent the click event and issue an imperative navigation action. I'll update with an example.

Comment: Thank you!! You helped me out a while ago for another question. Always appreciate your help and explanations. I've actually added a very similar scenario to my question above involving radio buttons. The text starting with "Similarly" explains that new case. Would you mind taking a look at that? If not possible, I understand. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @penguin I can take a look, but it's probably be best to post that as an entirely new SO post. If you do that then feel free to ping me here with a link to the new question and I can take a look when available.